# PDFtron webviewer window content disappears on browser window zoom in and zoom out and never appears again

Tags: pdftron, xfdf

I am using PDFTron WebViewer version 6.1.0 for a POC. I am facing issue with Webviewer content getting vanished when the browser zoom option is used (ctrl + and ctrl -) in firefox. Once the webviewer content disappears, it will not appear until the page which instantiates the webviewer is fully refreshed.
I am getting the below error in console during page zoom.

```
TypeError: "a.xM is not a function"
```

[image]

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Syed

Comment: Are you able to reproduce it on the PDFTron website? https://www.pdftron.com/samples/web/samples/viewing/viewing/ I was not able to see the issue there so maybe this is an issue with a customization that you've made. If you could provide more details about how to reproduce in an uncustomized viewer that would be helpful.